# C++ make a string raw using macros

Tags: c++, string, macros

So to make a string in C++ raw you do

```cpp
std::string raw = R"raw_string(text_here""n/whatever)raw_string"
```

but my question is can you make a macro that preprocesses the string ,
so its raw but it looks normal in code?? Like in a function argument

```cpp
#define start_raw_string R"raw_string(
#define end_raw_string )raw_string"

void example(std::string raw_text){
    std::cout << start_raw_string raw_text end_raw_string << std::endl;
// here all this  ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾   is
// an entire string ...
// equivalent to R"raw_string(<RAW_TEXT_HERE>)raw_string"
}
int main(){
    example("text_here""n/whatever");
    // will print >> text_here""n/whatever
}
```

as you can see by highlighting it will not work like this for sure
so any workaround? found something about macro glue-ing here
https://www.iar.com/knowledge/learn/programming/advanced-preprocessor-tips-and-tricks/

but tried it and cant get it to work... soo? it should be posibile because its not
compile-time.

Comment: The `std::string` is not "raw".  The C-string literal is raw.

Comment: is what i need posibile with C-String literals?

Comment: Yes, by doing `example(R"aw(text_here""n/whatever)aw");`.  But that appears to be what you are attempting to avoid.

Comment: can i do a macro like that inside the function?

Comment: what do you mean with "but it looks normal in code" ? Macros don't look "normal"

Comment: I dont understand how `start_raw_string` and `end_raw_string` are better than what you already have working. Why do you want to use a macro?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number so its doesnt contain things like R"start(text)start" , like those flags inside the string R , start( and )start

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i want to use macros so i dont need to use R"start( , )start" thats the thing im trying to avoid , so the function call looks clean

Comment: oh I think now I get it. Your `example` function is your attempt to turn the string literal into a raw string literal. Thats not possible. But I still wonder (sorry for being annoying ;). Do you really think `example(" some literal")` is that much better than the correct syntax ?

Comment: To look "normal" in code just try to use C++ as much as is, that way it's easier for other people (who only now C++ and not your Macros) to read your code. Macros IMO are a kind of last restort and should only be use if you can only solve an issue by invoking the preprocessor concatenation. In most other cases (variadic) function templates are the better option.

Comment: don't try to work around well accepted C++ syntax. Macros are good at that, but the resulting code will be terrible. Use the syntax that everybody familiar with C++ knows and can read, rather than obfuscating your code with macros.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it is better because the "C-literal" should be raw at all time and the thing im trying to do contains a lot of " , \n , \t and things , doing that R"" thing everytime takes space , when the actual text it need to print is 5 letters

Comment: frankly "takes space" is a rather poor measure for code. If you really want to save some characters use a shorter character sequence to denote start and end, `R"x(\n)x"` for example. Thats 5 characters more to have it clear and readable in the code that this is a raw string literal. I don't thing you can get it any cheaper

Comment: `R"(\n)"` is barely bigger than `"\\n"`. If you aren't using `)` then you don't need any delimiter.

Comment: Nobody needs macros to concatenate raw strings. Use a simple class template to keep string, make constexpr operators and all works as expected without such horrible things. 2022! No macros please! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot work like this. Once you passed the string literal to the function it is a `std::string` not a literal anymore. A string literal is the thing you type in your code. Its not something that you can pass around. Even if you'd pass a `char[N]` to the function it cannot work. You cannot turn a character array to a literal (hence also not to a raw literal).

Note that the syntax is like it is for a reason. The start/end character sequence appears right with the raw string literal, because the raw string literal cannot contain that sequence. Compare this:

```
std::cout << R"x()x")x";  // error
```

where it is obvious what the error is: The raw string literal cannot contain `)x"`, with this:

```
std::cout << macro_voodoo(")x") // error ?!?
```

which looks fine but would result in confusing error messages because the start and end character sequences are not visible in the code.

Write code for readability and clarity and don't try to work around C++ syntax. 5 characters to denote that a string literal is raw should be acceptable. And it can even be 3 only when you do not need the delimiter.